# Removing all destroyed objects from a list

Tags: unity, c#

I am a little confused on deleting objects in a List. I realise that clearing the list doesn't destroy the gameobject in Unity. Hence I have written this routine to destroy and remove:

```
//clear all block sprites away
for (int i = 0; i < blockSprites.Count; i++)
{
    Destroy(blockSprites[i]);
}
blockSprites.Clear();
```

But what if I only wanted to destroy *some* of the elements (a variable amount)?

In that scenario the List.Clear() function wouldn't work. Would I have to make another list of indexes in order to go through destroying and removing from the list in two sweeps. Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once a game object has been destroyed, it will compare as equal to null. So you can use [`List<T>.RemoveAll()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=net-5.0) to remove all the elements that compare as equal to null.

```
blockSprites.RemoveAll(s => s == null);
```

Comment: brilliant. Thanks for the help